# What's the difference in this javascript closure?

Tags: javascript, closures

What's the difference (in `num++`) between:

```
function numberGenerator() {
  // Local “free” variable that ends up within the closure
  var num = 1;
  function checkNumber() { 
    console.log(num);
  }
  num++;
  return checkNumber;
}

var number = numberGenerator();
number(); // 2
number(); // 2
number(); // 2
```

and

```
function numberGenerator() {
  // Local “free” variable that ends up within the closure
  var num = 1;
  function checkNumber() { 
    console.log(num);
    num++;
  }
  return checkNumber;
}

var number = numberGenerator();
number(); // 1
number(); // 2
number(); // 3
```

Why doesn't the first code remember the value of `num`?

Why is it 2 instead of 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact it does remember it very well. *num*'s variable-name-value is always 2, no matter how many time you persist in calling it; i.e.: the execution of the returned closure of the variable-name *number*.

It will forever remain 2.

That's because in the first function your closure

1. doesn't have a hold on *num* variable.
2. doesn't cause the *num* increase.
3. each call will be returning the result of the host function (num++)increase, which has happened only once. And its value is already 2.

All the same if you call *numberGenerator*, again because the *num* value will be re-declared / reset to 1 and than increased and self assigned a value 2 at its next declaration.

So, there is no difference, its just that the closure in your first, cannot increase the *num* variable value, since it doesn't have he means to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Because when you run `number()` in the first example, `num++` isn't executed again, because it's not in that function.

Answer (score 1):

Example 1 is initialized with `var num = 1;` and then increased with `num++;`. It doesn't matter how often you call the first function because the value of `num` is never changed again, it will always be 2. Only the `console.log(num);` is executed when you call `number()` in Example 1.

In Example 2 `num++;` is executed each time you invoke the function. Therefore it will increase with each call.

Comment: Excellent. So the reason num is 2 and not 1 is because at the initial assignment of number, it was incremented before the return keyword. On calling number, it will only execute and remember what's inside the inner function only??!

Answer (score 1):

At the time of function invocation (var number = numberGenerator), the closure 'checkNumber()' has access to the local variable 'num', and holds onto that value even after it is incremented with num++. The closure has direct access to the local variable 'num', and changes it each time it is accessed using the variable 'number'. This only works when num++ is inside of the closure, as the closure has direct access to the local variables in the function that it is contained in. Douglas Cockford's book "JavaScript: the good parts" has helped me a lot in creating and understanding closures.
I hope this helps!